# How to use different connections according to query type in Yii

Tags: php, dbconnection, yii

All my reads should go to one DB connection
All my writes should go to another connection

How do I accomplish this in Yii, with minimal changing the code of the core library?

And on occasions (as stated in the comments) I will need the ability to control each Model type of connection, so read can go to the Master too.

Comment: No experience with Yii and no answer, but let me point out that you probably still want to maintain the ability to read from master in situations where you need to guarantee you are reading the most up to date records (in case replication falls behind).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written an app where the master admin panel could be used to create and administer several customer-facing "instances", so there was the need to "direct" queries running inside the master app to any one of the instance-specific databases. I 'll illustrate a trimmed-down version what I did first (which is not as demanding as your goal) and present a more powerful approach afterwards.

### Using multiple databases for all queries

Directing queries to a database that has been specified from beforehand is easy: just override the [`CActiveRecord::getDbConnection`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getDbConnection-detail) method. What I did can be trimmed down to this:

```
abstract class InstanceActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord {
    public static $dbConnection = null;

    public function getDbConnection() {
        if (self::$dbConnection === null) {
            throw new CException('Database connection must be defined to work with instance records.');
        }

        return self::$dbConnection;
    }
}
```

So if you want to direct all operations to a specific database you simply have to derive your ActiveRecord models from `InstanceActiveRecord` instead of `CActiveRecord`, then just do `InstanceActiveRecord::dbConnection = $connection` and you are good to go.

### Using multiple databases with auto-selection based on query type

For this you need to go deeper into `CActiveRecord`. It turns out that `getDbConnection` is mostly used by [`getCommandBuilder`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getCommandBuilder-detail), which in turn is the method called by all the delete/update/insert families. So we need to pass some kind of context from those functions down to `getDbConnection`, where the choice of which connection we want to use will be made.

For this we 're going to have to override all methods in those families, so a reasonable approach might be:

**Step 1.** Add an optional parameter to `getDbConnection` and override it to return whichever connection you want it to based on the parameter value. The simplest would be something like this:

```
public function getDbConnection($writeContext = null) {
    if ($writeContext === null) {
        return parent::getDbConnection(); // to make sure nothing will ever break
    }

    // You need to get the values for $writeDb and $readDb in here somehow,
    // but this can be as trivially easy as you like (e.g. public static prop)
    return $writeContext ? $writeDb : $readDb;
}
```

**Step 2.** Add an optional parameter to `getCommandBuilder` with the same semantics and override it to forward the value:

```
public function getCommandBuilder($writeContext = null) {
    return $this->getDbConnection($writeContext)->getSchema()->getCommandBuilder();
}
```

**Step 3.** Find all call sites of `getCommandBuilder` (there will be a bunch of those) and `getDbConnection` (there were just 2 more than the one inside `getCommandBuilder` at the time I looked) and override them to specify the read/write context appropriately. Example:

```
public function deleteAll($condition='',$params=array()) {
    Yii::trace(get_class($this).'.deleteAll()','system.db.ar.CActiveRecord');

    // Just need to add the (true) value here to specify write context:
    $builder=$this->getCommandBuilder(true);
    $criteria=$builder->createCriteria($condition,$params);
    $command=$builder->createDeleteCommand($this->getTableSchema(),$criteria);
    return $command->execute();
}
```

After this you should be ready to go. There's also nothing stopping you from making a more involved context selection mechanism than the `true`/`false` option illustrated here, the concept is the same.

### Practical concerns

While all of this will achieve the stated goal perfectly, there remains a question regarding the maintainability of this approach.

It's true that going this route will involve lots of copy/pasted code from `CActiveRecord`, which is not ideal if there's the chance of moving your app to a later version of the framework later on; to do so, you will be forced to bring your subclass up to sync with the latest version of `CActiveRecord`.

To migitate this and make your life easier in the future, you can consider this approach:

1. Instead of copy/pasting and overriding only part of `CActiveRecord`, make an exact copy (minus the properties of course) of `CActiveRecord` and perform the changes there. In other words, copy over even those methods that you do *not* intend to override.
2. Perform the changes mentioned above. Remember that this involves an override of `getDbConnection` *and only really minor edits to a dozen or two of other places*.
3. Make your models extend the resulting class.

Now when the time comes to upgrade to a later Yii version, you will need to bring your class in sync with `CActiveRecord` again. Fire up your favorite diff tool and compare your class with the target version of `CActiveRecord`. The diff tool will show you only the `getDbConnection` and minor edits, plus whatever changes were made to `CActiveRecord` in Yii's core. Copy those other changes over to your class. Problem solved in 5 minutes tops.

Comment: just into my second day on Yii, would it be a smart move to attach a behavior to the ActiveRecord class that will replace the resident `getDbConnection` That way I do not touch the original code. Is this approach valid?

Comment: @ItayMoav: Unfortunately you [cannot override methods](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/#hh1) using behaviors: *The only caveat to this is an attached behavior cannot override any class methods of the component it is being attached to.*

Comment: @ktothez: Thanks. I had the advantage of having had to delve into this scenario in the past, and I am a believer in spreading knowledge.

Comment: Nice one Jon. A quick note that if you simply want to change the db for an individual connection you can simply modify the model with `$model::$db = $conn2;` where $conn2 is a CDbConnection object. (This method assumes your db schemas are the same.)